# Should I initiate size before loop and append in Python

Tags: python

I am going to build a 1,000,000 * 2 dataframe in Python and the input I have is in the form of 1*2. So obviously the most straightforward method is to use loop and append a 1*2 pair into the existing dataframe for 1,000,000 times... However, it really takes forever and as a Matlab user, I am almost forbidden in Matlab to do this and always told to initiate the final size of the matrix (or dataframe in Python) first and put elements into the matrix... Is this the same in Python? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to read from file?

Comment: my inputs are from a web-based xml file... I get input from there which is 1*2 pairs

Comment: Do you get them all at once, or separately?

Comment: i get them separately

Comment: you can make it and then initialize it. you can employ np.empty.

Comment: thanks. my question is if I initialize the dataframe, ie, pre-define the size, will make it much faster, like in Matlab?

Comment: Dataframes don't have final size as such? We can keep on adding the entries Also pandas requires nearly 2-3.5 times the memory the size of file

Comment: This is referred to as pre-allocation and is preferred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649788/optimal-way-to-append-to-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be just as slow as in matlab. You’re going to be copying the whole data frame every time you append something.